# Reverse engineer array dimensions / struct layout from compiler asm output?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

In this code, A and B are constants defined with `#define`.  What are the values of A and B?

```
typedef struct {
    int x[A][B];
    long y;
} str1;

typedef struct {
    char array[B];
    int t;
    short S[A];
    long u;
} str2;

void setVal(str1 *p, str2 *q) {
    long v1 = q->t;
    long v2 = q->u;
    p->y = v1+v2;
}
```

The following assembly code is generated for the `setVal` procedure:

```
setVal:
    movslq  8(%rsi), %rax
    addq   32(%rsi), %rax
    movq     %rax, 184(%rdi)
    ret
```

Comment: What part of the assembly are you having trouble with? (Also: What do you mean by "formatted something like this"? Do you mean that you'd rather it not have been compiled for x86_64?)

Comment: actually disregard the last part, @duskwuff I just need help understanding the whole problem as a whole to be honest. the Process of finding what the values of A and B are.

Comment: Fun puzzle. Hint: it's all about structure padding.

Comment: [Similar Q&A here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466018/how-to-reverse-engineer-struct-details-from-c-source-and-asm-output), (which led to some confusion because the poster of that question didn't realize the code was different from this, and was asking for an explanation of why A==5 and B==6, when that's not the right answer for the other question.)  Note that the new question is easier, because in that one you can solve for `B` right away without any ambiguity (since a narrow type follows an array of wide elements, so there won't be padding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure has the following alignment requirements:

- a `char` may start at any byte
- a `short` may start at even byte
- an `int` may start at byte, divisible by four
- a `long` may start at byte, divisible by eight

The `str1.y` field is a `long` and starts at `184`, this implies, that `str1.x` may hold either `184` or `180` bytes.

The `str2.t` field is an `int` and starts at `8`, this implies, that `str1.array` may hold from `5` to `8` bytes.

The `str2.u` field is a `long` and starts at `32`, this implies, that `str2.S` may hold from `14` to `20` bytes.

This is the diagram for `str1` structure fields:

```
+---------------+---+--------+
|  int x[A][B]  | ? | long y |
+---------------+---+--------+
|        184        |    8   |
+-------------------+--------+
```

And this is the diagram for `str2` fields:

```
+---------------+---+-------+------------+---+--------+
| char array[B] | ? | int t | short S[A] | ? | long u |
+---------------+---+-------+------------+---+--------+
|         8         |   4   |        20      |    8   |
+-------------------+-------+----------------+--------+
```

After that, you should solve the following system:

```
177 <= 4 * A * B <= 184
5 <= B <= 8
14 <= A * 2 <= 20      // 7 <= A <= 10
```

The answer is: `A = 9`, `B = 5`

---

You can test your answer (and the ranges for each inequality) using a compiler that follows the same ABI / calling convention used by the compiler that produced the original code.  It uses 8-byte `long`: note the 64-bit operand size for the `addq`, instead of `addl`, and the 8-byte store.  Thus, we can infer that it's most likely the x86-64 System V ABI, not the Windows x86-64 calling convention (which uses 4-byte `long`).

The Godbolt compiler explorer has gcc, clang, ICC, and MSVC.  The first 3 target Linux, but MSVC targets the Windows calling convention and thus won't agree on struct layout with a smaller `long` requiring less alignment.

[Replacing `int x[A][B]` with `char t[177]` (or other sizes)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23define+A+1%0A%23define+B+44%0A%0Atypedef+struct+%7B%0A++++//int+x%5BA%5D%5BB%5D%3B%0A++++char+t%5B177%5D%3B++//+177+to+184+gives+us+184(%25rdi)%0A++++long+y%3B%0A%7D+str1%3B%0A%0Atypedef+struct+%7B%0A++++char+array%5BB%5D%3B%0A++++int+t%3B%0A++++short+S%5BA%5D%3B%0A++++long+u%3B%0A%7D+str2%3B%0A%0Avoid+setVal(str1+*p,+str2+*q)+%7B%0A++++long+v1+%3D+q-%3Et%3B%0A++++long+v2+%3D+q-%3Eu%3B%0A++++p-%3Ey+%3D+v1%2Bv2%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.09065675066269,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang401,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:64.90934324933733,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) proves that 177 is the minimum and 184 is the maximum size that that leads to a store to `184(%rdi)`.  So we could have written `176 < 4*A*B <= 184`.  Or, to keep things to multiples of 4, `180 <= 4*A*B <= 184` is also more or less correct; we can rule out 177..179 based on the size of `int`.

Comment: Should be `<= 4 * A * B <= 184` instead of `<= A * B <= 184`?

Comment: @A.Grow: your edit introduced an error.  Were you thinking of `176 < 4*A*B <= 184`?  That's true with `<`, but not with `<=`.  Try it on the Godbolt link I added to the question, and see that the asm output is different with only 176 bytes of array before `str1::y`.