# How to reverse engineer struct details from C source and asm output?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly

**I'm trying to understand the solution to this problem**:

Given the C code below, and the asm output from the compiler, what are `A` and `B`?

Answer: `A` is 5, `B` is 6.

I am guessing there has to be some sort of division done, because 96 and 48 are both divisible by 6 and 20 is divisible by 5.

EDIT: **I found this explanation for the answer online. However I am not sure if it is accurate**

" a char starts at any BYTE

a short starts only at EVEN bytes

an int starts at BYTE, but divisible by 4

a long starts at BYTE which is divisible by 8

str1.w is long which starts at 5 to 8

str1.x may have 184 or 180

str2.p is int starts at the value 8, hence str1.array which holds from 5 to 8 BYTES

str2.q short may be 14 to 20

str2.z may be 32

char w[A][B] and int X

8                              184

Str2.

short[B]      int p        doublez[B]          short q

20                  4                 8                          9

hence the value of A=5 and B=6"

*****Code below:*****

```
// #define A  ??   // 5
// #define B  ??   // 6, but the question is how to figure that out from the asm
typedef struct {
    char w[A][B];
    int x;
} str1;

typedef struct {
    short y[B];
    int p;
    double z[B];
    short q; 
} str2;

void doSub(str1 *t, str2 *u) {
    int v1 = u->p;
    int v2 = u->q;
    t->x = v1-v2;
}
```

**Assembly code generated for doSub procedure:**

```
# t in %rdi, u in %rsi
doSub:
    movswl   96(%rsi), %edx
    movl     20(%rsi), %eax
    subl     %edx, %eax
    movl     %eax, 48(%rdi)
    ret
```

Comment: Please remove the image and replace it with the code. Images are discouraged since they are not search friendly.

Comment: @RSahu working on it

Comment: @kaylum they're not given, the point is to *derive* them from the given structures, C code, and generated assembly code. Think of it as a "Given the following, What are possible values of `A` and `B` ? Explain why."

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, that is a bit clearer the way you explain it. But, at least for me, it doesn't come across so clear the way the question is currently worded. Would be good for OP to make that more explicit.

Comment: @Pauline Wait I'm still lost. Are you telling us that `A=5` and `B=6` and you're curious how that assembly was generated based on those values for `A` and `B`?   .. Ok just saw your edit

Comment: @yano no, he's telling us that given only the C code and its generated assembly, one should be able to *deduce* the values of `A` and `B`, that he has been told (or peeked to the answer) that the values are 5 and 6 respectively, and he simply wants to know how they were found.

Comment: @yano Lets say only the C code and assembly code was given. How would you find the values of A and B with only this information? That is what I need clarification on

Comment: WhozCraig is correct

Comment: @WhozCraig ahhh ok,, thanks.  Interesting question

Comment: From [your friend](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6004898/nick-predey) (supposedly): "You're in my COMP 264 class with Dr. Greenberg. I totally see you trying to get this answer on Stack Overflow. You shouldn't be trying to fish for answers on the internet. Where are your Jesuit values?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asm is clearly for the [AMD64 SysV ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) (more links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).  I conclude that from it being x86-64 code with the first two args in `%rdi`, `%rsi`.  The alignment rules given in the answer you found do match the ABI's rules for struct layout:  Those types have their natural alignments.  (n-byte types are n-byte aligned, except for 10B long double (x87 format) which is 16B-aligned).

---

**The answer you found doesn't match your C and asm**, so the A and B values are different.  Sorry I didn't check this while tidying up the question, I just assumed since it's trivial to check the answer with a compiler.

The [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33604000/224132) you found does indeed have different structs and different asm output, so any similarity in the numeric solution is just a coincidence.  Nice work @MichaelPetch for finding the original source (and copying the markdown with formatting into the question).

---

The following code produces identical asm to what your actual problem, with [gcc 5.3 -O3 on the godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dgnu11+-fverbose-asm+-O3+-fno-tree-vectorize+-mtune%3Dgeneric',source:'%23define+A++5%0A%23define+B++9%0Atypedef+struct+%7B%0A++++char+w%5BA%5D%5BB%5D%3B++++++//+from+0+to+A*B+-+1%0A++++int+x%3B+++++++++++++//+offset+%3D+48+%3D+A*B+padded+to+a+4B+boundary%0A%7D+str1%3B%0A%0Atypedef+struct+%7B%0A++++short+y%5BB%5D%3B++++++++//+2*B+bytes%0A++++int+p%3B+++++++++++++//+offset+%3D+20+%3D+2*B+rounded+up+to+a+4byte+boundary%0A++++double+z%5BB%5D%3B+++++++//+starts+at+24+(20%2B4,+already+8byte+aligned),+ends+at+24+%2B+8*B+-+1%0A++++short+q%3B+++++++++++//+offset+%3D+96+%3D+24+%2B+8+*+B%0A%7D+str2%3B%0A%0Avoid+doSub(str1+*t,+str2+*u)+%7B%0A++++int+v1+%3D+u-%3Ep%3B%0A++++int+v2+%3D+u-%3Eq%3B%0A++++t-%3Ex+%3D+v1-v2%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

```
#define A  5
#define B  9
typedef struct {
    char w[A][B];      // stored from 0 to A*B - 1
    int x;             // offset = 48 = A*B padded to a 4B boundary
} str1;

typedef struct {
    short y[B];        // 2*B bytes
    int p;             // offset = 20 = 2*B rounded up to a 4byte boundary
    double z[B];       // starts at 24 (20+4, already 8byte aligned), ends at 24 + 8*B - 1
    short q;           // offset = 96 = 24 + 8 * B
} str2;

void doSub(str1 *t, str2 *u) {
    int v1 = u->p;
    int v2 = u->q;
    t->x = v1-v2;
}
```

I added in what we know from the asm as comments on the structs.

- `str2` only depends on B, and has no ambiguity, so we can solve for `B` before worrying about `A`:

  `96 = 24 + 8 * B`
  `72 = 8 * B`
  `72/8 = 9 = B`
- Once we have `B`, `str1` gives us `A`:

  `48 = align4(A*B) = align4(A*9)`
  `45 <= A*9 <= 48`
  `5 <= A <= 5.333`
  Only one integer solution: `A == 5`

Although honestly it was faster to solve by trial and error, since the compiler explorer site re-compiles automatically after any change.  It was easy to iterate towards the right value for B to produce the 96 and 20 offsets.

Your `A` was already correct, but homing in on that would have been easy, since the problem was separable.  There was never a 2 simultaneous equations in 2 unknowns situation.

---

This is where the "solution" starts to wander off track.  Are you sure it was a solution to the exact same problem you posted?

> `str1.w` is long which starts at 5 to 8
>   `str1.x` may have 184 or 180

`str1.w` in the code you posted is a 2-dimensional array of `char`, and starts at the beginning of the struct.

`str1.x` starts at 48 bytes into `str1`, as we can see from the asm.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: that was the conclusion I eventually came to.  Updated the wording to match better.  And I was just about to make basically the same edit to the question, but you beat me to it. :P

Comment: @MichaelPetch That was not where I found the answer. In the question you edited into my problem A=9 an B=5, but the solution I found was to the exact same question as mine and the solution (not official solution) had the answers written as A=5 and B=6

Comment: @Pauline, I saw a boneheaded and terribly bogus answer on Chegg for this answer that gave 5 and 6. Did you get your answer from a site like Chegg?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes I saw it on Chegg!

Answer (score 8):

The assembly code tells you the offsets of the fields used in the C code.  So from that, you can tell

```
offsetof(str1, x) == 48
offsetof(str2, p) == 20
offsetof(str2, q) == 96
```

Now lets look at `p`.  It comes after `y` and `sizeof(short)` is probably 2 (unless this is a pretty unusual machine or compiler), so that tells us `B*2 + padding == 20`.  So B is at most 10, and probably not 8 or less.

Looking at `q`, `sizeof(double)` is probably 8 (again, unless unusual), so `20 + sizeof(int) + 8*B + padding == 96`.  If `sizeof(int) == 4` (common, though different sizes for int are more common than for short/double), that gives us `8*B + padding == 72`.  So B is at most 9.  Since `short` probably has less restrictive alignment than `double`, there's probably no padding, giving `B==9`, consistent with 2 bytes of padding before `p`

Looking at `str`, `sizeof(char) == 1` (always), so `A*9 + padding = 48`.  So the most likely value for `A` is 5, with 3 bytes of padding.

Of course, the compiler is free to add any padding it wants, so any smaller values for `A` and `B` are possible, though wasteful.

Comment: It's safe to assume (based on args in rdi, rsi) that the asm is compiler output targeting the [AMD64 SysV ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf), where `sizeof(short) == 2`, `sizeof(int) == 4`, and `sizeof(double) == 8`.  And where those types normally have their natural alignment (outside of `__attribute__((packed))` or similar).  Fun fact: `long double` is 80 bit x87 format, but with 16B alignment.

Comment: Nice assessment. I'm still trying to see how the OP's claim the answer is "A is 5, B is 6" holds, unless they had a dyslexic moment on the latter value.

Comment: @WhozCraig I can't see any ABI where A=5 and B=6 could be true. That would mean that char[A*B] == 30*(bytes in char). offsetof(str1, x) == 48. This automatically limits us to a 1 byte char since 48 < 60. I don't see how there could be an alignment of int where 30 + alignment == 48 can work when 30 + alignment == 32 doesn't work. Unless someone invented an ABI where integers must be aligned at odd multiples of 16.. (I've worked with crazy hardware before, but never this crazy). A=5, B=9 is the correct answer.

Comment: @Art I concur, for every reason you and Chris mentioned.

Comment: @Art: You can align also each "row" of char w, so then you are solving A*(9+padding1)+padding2 == 48, for example you may want to align it to 16 (padding1=7) to get simple `some_w_value = w[index1<<4+index2];` instead of `some_w_value = w[index1*9+index2];` ... but if you consider such optimization, then 1 <= A <= 5 is basically all you can tell about A for sure.

Comment: `B` must be exactly 9; see my answer.  This is 64bit x86; there are no standard ABIs for that platform where `short`, `int`, and `double` aren't what we expect.  The OP must have found an answer to a similar problem with different code, because the posted solution wanders off track.  @Pauline: can you edit in a link to where you found this answer?  It clearly doesn't match your question.  And also fix the formatting of the "solution" you edited in?  It's pretty terrible.

Comment: @Ped7g: I don't think ISO C allows multidimensional arrays to be discontiguous like that.  You could only get behaviour like that if each row was a struct.