# Finding size of 2D array in disassembled C code

Tags: assembly, memory, x86-64, reverse-engineering

Currently trying to work through a CTF that requires me to find the dimensions of a 2 dimensional array via disassembled objdump of a compiled binary I suspect was written in C (I know for sure each of them is square, and stored in row-major order). I know that one section puts a constant within each of these arrays at different positions.

There is also some initialization happening in .data, I think? But I'm really lost as to how I'm supposed to approach a problem like this. Does anyone have any pointers (pun intended) on calculating 2D array dimensions from objdump?

Anyways, here's where the constant gets added to each. I know the positions that they are added in:

```
0000000000401243 <add_cells>:
  401243:   55                      push   %rbp
  401244:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  401247:   b8 ef be ad de          mov    $0xdeadbeef,%eax
  40124c:   48 89 05 0d 58 03 00    mov    %rax,0x3580d(%rip)        # 436a60 <firstArray+0x14a0>
  401253:   48 89 05 86 5a 02 00    mov    %rax,0x25a86(%rip)        # 426ce0 <secondArray+0x3d40>
  40125a:   48 89 05 9f 5d 00 00    mov    %rax,0x5d9f(%rip)        # 407000 <thirdArray+0x2bc0>
  401261:   90                      nop
  401262:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  401263:   c3                      ret
```

This is for homework, so please don't give me the answer to the size if you can glean it from this. I am just looking for some guidance and understanding.

Comment: You can't calculate from this as it does not use indices. Also according to the symbols printed these are 3 separate arrays.

Comment: Usually these array-dimension reverse-engineering problems give you a function that takes two indices as runtime variables, like [Reverse engineering and interpreting assembly code](//stackoverflow.com/q/67732896) / [Nested Arrays in Assembly, reach desired index](//stackoverflow.com/q/72467662) /  [Finding the dimensions of an array through assembly](//stackoverflow.com/q/39550678) / [deriving size of array from assembly code and skeleton C](//stackoverflow.com/q/69478687)

Comment: Or you have source with placeholders for dimensions with the arrays inside structs, so you can work out what the sizes must be from code that accesses struct members past  the array, like [Reverse engineer array dimensions / struct layout from compiler asm output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33603082).  Either way, you have enough info to construct at least two equations in two unknowns and can solve for everything.  Unlike in your case where you only have one access to each of three arrays, without any info about what indices are being used for each of the three accesses.

Comment: These values could be last element of each array `0x14a0`,`0x3d40`,`0x2bc0`. `%rax` is inserted there. Each value is 8 byte long. So if we divide those values by 8 we get number of elements in each array.